# How to access local variables from a different page flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use the value of myAddress/myPcode in a different page.

```
crudObj.getDataFromUserFromDocument().then((value) {
                Map<String, dynamic> dataMap = value
              .data; 
          setState(() {
            _fullNames = dataMap['name'];
            profilPicture = dataMap['picture'];
            _notificationValue = dataMap['notification'];
            myAddress = dataMap['address'];
            myPcode = dataMap['postalCode'];
            print(myPcode);
            print(myAddress);
          });
        });
      }
```

Comment: You want to access the variables only in one page?

Comment: I want to access the string from another class in a different page

Comment: What does the other class exactly do? Is it a widget that you want to update it when you retrieve new `myPcode` and `myAddress`?

Comment: Are these values that need to be permanent, or just while the user is on the app? If it is the latter then you can either pass the values when instantiating the other class, as was already answered below, or you can use an InheritedWidget wrapping your app to share data between any widget in your tree.

Comment: I'm trying to use the variable the variable  myAddress  to filter database items

Answer (score 0):

There are many options to use the string from any other Screen or Class.

1. While navigating to another Screen create a constructor and send the data through parameters.

   ```
    class packageScreen extends StatefulWidget {
         String username;
         String email;
         String token;

         packageScreen(this.username,this.email,this.token);

         @override
         _packageScreenState createState() => _packageScreenState();
      }
   ```
2. (the Most preferable way in your case)Save the String in Shared Preference and get the value from any other Screen.
   https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences